# sudo: Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for [username]

Tags: sudo, samba

I have been setting up an ubuntu server and at some point this started to happen:

Every time I sudo and am prompted for a password I get this:

```
sudo echo "test"
[sudo] password for [username]:
Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for [username]
Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for [username]
test
```

I have a feeling it might have to do something with samba, but I am not sure, and googling hasn't showed me anything definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this exact same problem arise on our Ubuntu server.  You are exactly correct.  The answer lies with Samba.  That particular message seems to be printing out because the Samba debug level is set too high.  Because Samba integrates with `pam` for authentication, it shows up at `sudo` and `su` prompts, as they also use `pam` to authenticate.

The relevant line in `smb.conf` is:

```
debug level = n
```

where `n` is a number from `0` to `10`.  If you're using Webmin, it's in miscellaneous options. (Edit: it was called `log level` in my smb.conf).

We had our debug set to `3` when we were testing today.  Setting it back to `0` resolved the issue.
I did some testing, and the highest that the debug can be without seeing the message seems to be `2`

---

Also, I ran into the same issue with Google.  This question was the only relevant search result I found.

Comment: Isn't it `log level` instead of `debug level`? Although on level 2 it seems to have gone.